# Show Asked/Answered timestamp instead of just Edited in app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, timestamps

When viewing a question/answer in the app, the (in my opinion) less relevant *Edited* timestamp is shown, rather than *Asked* or *Answered*. I'd hate to lose *Edited* entirely, so how's about flipping between the two or something?

[image: This picture is worth 50,000 words]